# Scan Conversion/Bresenham algorithm in MIPS not functioning

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to make a mips program that will print an entire line using only spaces and *, to denote pixels.

For an input of a horizontal line it functions perfectly.

But the vertical does not print correctly and when I tried to implement the Bresenham algorithm and use that to find the pixels I doesn't.

Either the program will go into a infinite loop for not print out correctly.

Thank you for taking the to look at and possible help.

As I have test the program I realized non of the inputs print correct and the program loops for times then expect

```
.data
msg1:   .asciiz " " 
msg2:   .asciiz "*" 
msg3:   .asciiz "\n"
msg4:   .asciiz "\n------"

xArray:  .space 80
yArray:  .space 80

.text

main:
add $s0, $0, 5 #x1 These four values don't print correctly
add $s1, $0, 0 #y1 They print at (0,0) - (0,5) 

add $s2, $0, 5 #x2 They should print through (5,0) - (5,5) 
add $s3, $0, 5 #y2

jal lineScanConversionFunc

add $s0, $0, 0 #x1 These four values do print correctly
add $s1, $0, 5 #y1

add $s2, $0, 5 #x2 
add $s3, $0, 5 #y2

jal lineScanConversionFunc

add $s0, $0, 2 #x1 These values get stuck inside of loop to add values to the array
add $s1, $0, 3 #y1

add $s2, $0, 8 #x2
add $s3, $0, 7 #y2

jal lineScanConversionFunc

j finish
lineScanConversionFunc:
li $t0, 0
sb $s0, xArray($t0)
sb $s1, yArray($t0)

addi $t0, $t0, 4
sb $s2, xArray($t0)
sb $s3, yArray($t0)

beq $s0,$s2, horiz
beq $s1,$s3, vert

sub $s4, $s3, $s1 #y2 - y1, ^y
sub $s5, $s2, $s0 #x2 - x1, ^x

add $s6, $s4, $s4 #2^y
add $s7, $s5, $s5 #2^x

sub $t2,$s6,$s7 #2^y - 2^x
sub $t3,$s6,$s5 #2^y - x, P0

add $t1, $t1,$zero
addi $t1, $t1, 2

slt $t4, $zero, $t3
beq $t4, $zero, less
j greater

less: #(x+1,y) #The loop that gets suck is from here
addi $t0, $t0, 4
addi $s0,$s0,1
sb $s0, xArray($t0)
sb $s1, yArray($t0) 

add $t3,$t3,$s6

beq $t1, $s5, display
j keepGoing

greater:     #(x+1,y+1)
addi $t0, $t0, 4
addi $s0,$s0,1
addi $s1,$s1,1
sb $s0, xArray($t0)
sb $s1, yArray($t0) 

add $t3,$t3,$t2
beq $t1, $s5, display

j keepGoing

keepGoing:      
addi $t1, $t1, 1 
slt $t4, $zero, $t3
beq $t4, $zero, less
j greater #Here is the location of the other end of the loop the third value gets suck in
horiz:
beq $s1,$s3, display
addi $s1,$s1, 1

addi $t0, $t0, 4
sb $s0, xArray($t0)
sb $s1, yArray($t0)
j horiz
vert:
beq $s0,$s2, display
addi $s0,$s0, 1

addi $t0, $t0, 4
sb $s0, xArray($t0)
sb $s3, yArray($t0)
j vert  
display:                
add $t1, $0, 0 #index

add $t2, $0, 0 #x lowest
div $t3, $t0, 4 #x higest

add $t4, $t3, $0 #y higest

loadArraySearch:
lb $t5, xArray($t1)
lb $t6, yArray($t1)

beq $t2, $t5, xEquals
#j printSpace
j arrayIncrease             

 xEquals:
beq $t4, $t6, printDot
#j printSpace
 j arrayIncrease
 printSpace:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1
syscall

j loadArraySearch

 printDot:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall

j xIncrease

printLine:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg3
syscall

j loadArraySearch   

arrayIncrease:
beq $t1, $t0 xIncrease
addi $t1, $t1, 4
j loadArraySearch

xIncrease:  
beq $t2, $t3, yDecrease
addi $t2, $t2, 1
add $t1, $zero, 0
j loadArraySearch
yDecrease:
beq $t4, $zero, return
subi $t4, $t4, 1
add $t2, $zero, 0
add $t1, $zero, 0
j printLine
return: 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg4
syscall

jr $ra
finish:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: *Either the program will go into a infinite loop for not print out correctly.*  With what inputs?  And which loop does it get stuck in?  Use your debugger to find out, and make this a [mcve].  (FYI, the MARS simulator has a bitmap graphics mode where you can store pixels on a framebuffer, in case you'd rather write for that instead of printing text.  But that's fine too.)

Comment: add $s0, $0, 5 #x1
add $s1, $0, 0 #y1

add $s2, $0, 5 #x2
add $s3, $0, 5 #y2
Input does not print correctly add $s0, $0, 2 #x1
add $s1, $0, 3 #y1

add $s2, $0, 8 #x2
add $s3, $0, 7 #y2 get stuck in a loop while in greater/ less section, its meant to add the values using the algorithm to the arrays, but somehow got stuck

Comment: [edit] your question with more info, maybe mark the line with comments in the code block as well as describe in text which loop it is.  Use your debugger to find which branch you expect to fall through or jump out of the loop but instead keeps looping, and show what the register values are there.